# rspec stub variable in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to test an action form controller, in my action I have something like this

```
def my_action
  @user_collection = DB.get("users")
  users = @user_collection.find({"name" => "123"})
  result_hash = {}
  users.each do |user|
    # populate result_hash here
  end

  render :json => result_hash
end
```

Now I want to replace the users hash/array by some test values and to check the json output,

I tried in this way (spec)

```
controller.stub!(:users).and_return(my_users_arr)
get :my_action

response.body.should == {1 => 3}
```

but I got this error:
undefined method `stub!' for 'MyController:0x007fde91fd0418'

Answer (score -1):

You are 'stubbing' it wrong. Start from refactoring controller code:

```
def my_action
  render :json => users_hash
end


def users_hash
  result = {}
  # generate users hash 
  # ...
  result
end
```

Then, try this in test method:

```
controller.stub!(:users_hash).and_return(my_users_hash)
get :my_action
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are another way to 'fake' an variable in my action?